# Programatically create an IIS website on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I try to create a site problematically.

My code :

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();

protected void btnCreateSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Site mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add("MySiteName6", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot", 8070);
    serverMgr.ApplicationPools.Add("MyAppPool5");
    mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "MyAppPool";
    mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Enabled = true;
    mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Directory = "C:\\inetpub\\customfolder\\site";

    serverMgr.CommitChanges();
}
```

But when I open IIS I am not seeing  `MySiteName6`. When I try to run `http://localhost:8070` its not exist.

I am unable to understand where the site is gone? Am I in wrong direction.

Comment: Did you refresh the IIS manager?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Ya i refresh but still unable to see. :(